# Entities do not auto relocate to joined nodes

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

Question about sharding. Should entities relocate automatically when a new node joined? A have a singleton actor that sends a message to every entities in its onRecoveryCompleted handler, and all entities end up running on the same node as the Singleton runs (OK). After another node joined, the half of entities *do not relocate to it* (as I expect), but, if the Singleton sends a message to a new entity, it's spawned on the second node (OK), so the sharding seems to work, in general.

Answer (score 0):

That's something probably related with your configuration (or the default configuration), try to modify the properties `akka.cluster.sharding.rebalance-interval` (default 10 seconds) and most probably `akka.cluster.sharding.least-shard-allocation-strategy.rebalance-threshold` to adapt them to your expected use case. You can find more info in the [configuration documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html#configuration) and also the [Shard Rebalancing section](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html#shard-rebalancing).

Comment: Thanks you, please look at my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new node with a shard region, akka will check `the difference between most and least number of allocated shards` among all shard regions in a cluster. If the difference is bigger than `akka.cluster.sharding.least-shard-allocation-strategy.rebalance-threshold` (see [configuration documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html#configuration)), akka will start rebalancing shards. When a shard is restarted due rebalance and `akka.cluster.sharding.remember-entities` set to `on`, the shard will restart its entities (by default `akka.cluster.sharding.remember-entities` set to `off` and all shards lose all their entities after rebalancing).

So if you have one node with the shard region having 20 shards and you add a new node with a shard region and the difference between the old node shards number (20) and the new node shard number (0) bigger than `akka.cluster.sharding.least-shard-allocation-strategy.rebalance-threshold` value and `akka.cluster.sharding.remember-entities` set to `on`, akka will rebalance 10 shards into the new node and these shards will restart their entities after rebalance.

Comment: Thanks. I set `akka.cluster.sharding.least-shard-allocation-strategy.rebalance-threshold = 2` and `akka.cluster.sharding.rebalance-interval = 3 s`, but rebalance happens after exactly 10 seconds after the seconds node joined.

Comment: I might be late to the party - But, by default akka sets a back-off interval. According to the configuration documentation in https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html#configuration, Rebalance check is performed periodically with this interval.
  rebalance-interval = 10 s